# Online tool for diagonalizing matrices?

Tags: matrices, online-resources

I need some online tool for diagonalizing 2x2 matrices or at least finding the eigenvectors and eigenvalues of it. I don't like to download any stuf because I'm not able to, some online tool will do the job.
Thanks.

Comment: Wolfram Alpha works. Try [this](http://tinyurl.com/2vtv897).

Comment: @Guesswhoitis. Of course, WolframAlpha pretty much can do everything, and it's free so it's awesome.

Answer (score 8):

Wolframalpha has an option. Try this: http://www.wolframalpha.com/examples/Matrices.html

Answer (score 4):

Let $A$ be your $2$ by $2$ diagonalizable matrix, let $\lambda$ and $\mu$ be its eigenvalues, and let $I$ be the $2$ by $2$ identity matrix.

If $\lambda=\mu$, then $A=\lambda I$ and there is nothing to do.

If $\lambda\not=\mu$, then the nonzero columns of $A-\mu I$ (such always exist) are $\lambda$-eigenvectors.

[Recall that the eigenvalues of $$\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\ c&d\end{pmatrix}$$ are the roots of $X^2-(a+d)\,X+ad-bc$.]

[There is an obvious generalization to $n$ be $n$ matrices: in the above recipe to get a  $\lambda$-eigenvector, replace $A-\mu I$ by the product of the $A-\mu I$, where $\mu$ runs over the eigenvalues not equal to $\lambda$.]

To prove this in the $2$ by $2$ case, it suffices to check 
$$A^2-(a+d)\,A+(ad-bc)\,I=0,$$ which is straightforward. This is (a particular case of) the [Cayley-Hamilton Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley%E2%80%93Hamilton_theorem).

Comment: The OP is asking for online tools.

Comment: Dear @Rasmus: Thanks. I agree. [The OP doesn’t seem to be around anyway, but this changes nothing.] I just wanted to make sure the (virtual) OP was aware that s/he was asking for online tools for solving a *quadratic equation*. I suspect that s/he was *not* aware of that. Some people believe that to find the eigenvectors in this case you must solve linear systems. [There are probably more online tools that solve quadratic equations than online tools that diagonalize matrices. This tells the OP which kind of online tools are needed.] ... But I'm open to dialogue...

Comment: I see your point now. Thank you for the explanation. +1

Answer (score 3):

Try the [Online Matrix Calculator](http://www.bluebit.gr/matrix-calculator/).

Comment: And which option does the $S \Lambda S^{-1}$ decomposition? I do not see it.

Comment: @Val, check Eigenvalues/eigenvectors.

Comment: It produces you the list of eigenvalues/eigenvectors. It does not put them into the $S \Lambda S^{-1}$ form, which is what I call "diagonalization". http://matrixcalc.org/en.index.html does.

Comment: It may only be temporary, but the link to blubit software's onlline matrix calculator is down.

Comment: @hardmath, I think it has migrated to http://www.dotnumerics.com/MatrixCalculator/ . But nowadays WA seems preferable.

Answer (score 1):

http://matrixcalc.org/en.index.html decomposes the matrix into $S \Lambda S^{-1}$

Comment: It requires the eigenvalues to be rational, which is quite stupid. Otherwise it displays "Not Enough Rational Eigenvalues".